# Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) Compile error: Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors

I get the above error when trying to return and call a value from a function; here is my source code:

```
Private Function Fence_Change()
  Contents = Fence.Text
  Range("D4:ZZ4").Clear
  Range("D5:ZZ5").Clear
  Output = ""
  For Counter = 1 To Len(Contents)
      Cells(4, Counter + 3) = Mid(Contents, Counter, 1)
      Output = Output + Mid(Contents, Counter, 1)
      Counter = Counter + 1
  Next Counter
  For Counter = 2 To Len(Contents)
      Cells(5, Counter + 3) = Mid(Contents, Counter, 1)
      Output = Output + Mid(Contents, Counter, 1)
      Counter = Counter + 1
  Next Counter
  Fence_Change = Output
End Function
Private Sub Fence_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Output1 = Fence_Change()
    MsgBox (Output1)
End Sub
```

Using the VBA IDE for Office (Excel) 2016.
I've seen many others with similar problems, but still can't seem to be able to fix it, can anyone assist with this?
May also be useful to know that I already returned and called another function the same way without any errors:

```
Private Function Difficulty_Select()
  Set List = New Collection
  Select Case Difficulty
  Case "Easy"
      DifficultyInt = 10
      DifficultyOption = "Easy"
  Case "Medium"
      DifficultyInt = 25
      DifficultyOption = "Medium"
  Case "Hard"
      DifficultyInt = 50
      DifficultyOption = "Hard"
  End Select
  List.Add DifficultyInt
  List.Add DifficultyOption
  Set Difficulty_Select = List
End Function
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   MsgBox ("Hello, welcome to a quiz")
   Name = InputBox("What is your name?")
   Sheets("All results").Unprotect
   Score = 0
   Set List1 = Difficulty_Select()
   ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `Fence` is a control, it has a `Change` event already, which is a Sub, not a Function. You cannot create your own Function with the same name, even if you are not actually sinking the built-in `Change` event.

Answer (score 0):

As Rory suggests, `Fence` looks like it is a `Control`, so `Fence_Change` is the handler for the `Change` event, and should be a `Sub` procedure.

You could try re-organizing your code so that the `Fence_Change` event *and* the `Fence_DblClick` Event call a *common* function, like this:

```
Private Sub Fence_Change()
  GetOutput Fence.Text
End Sub

Private Sub Fence_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Output1 = GetOutput(Fence.Text)
    MsgBox Output1
End Sub

'This is the new helper function
Private Function GetOutput(contents As String) as String
  Range("D4:ZZ4").Clear
  Range("D5:ZZ5").Clear
  Output = ""
  For Counter = 1 To Len(Contents)
      Cells(4, Counter + 3) = Mid(Contents, Counter, 1)
      Output = Output + Mid(Contents, Counter, 1)
      Counter = Counter + 1
  Next Counter
  For Counter = 2 To Len(Contents)
      Cells(5, Counter + 3) = Mid(Contents, Counter, 1)
      Output = Output + Mid(Contents, Counter, 1)
      Counter = Counter + 1
  Next Counter
  GetOutput = Output
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

If it is windows 7 ultimate with service pack 1. Just remove the service pack or uninstall it. That solve the problem.

Comment: You need to give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. See more details on how to answer at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer